# CodeIgniter how to get from Model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to learn PHP with the newest CodeIgniter framework, but I'm having some problems. I can't tell if I'm just having some bad luck or if I'm missing some fundamental concepts.

Here's my View/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php foreach($forums as $f): ?>
<table>
<tr><td style="background-color:#ccc; font-weight:bold border: 1px solid black;">
<?php echo $f['name']; ?>
</td></tr></table><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's my Models/index.php :

```
class Index_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function getIndexListing(){
        $query = $this->db->query('Select name from Forums where parentid=0 order by sortorder asc');
        $rows =  $query->result_array();
        $query->free_result();  
    }  
}
```

And here's my Controllers/index.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Index extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // load users model
        if (! isset($this->Index_Model))
        {
        //   $this->load->model( 'Index_Model' );
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['forums']= $this->Index_Model->getIndexListing();
        $data['title'] = 'Welcome!';
        $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
    }
}
```

Problem : I can't figure out how to call `getIndexListing()` . When I do as I have here, I get the error `Undefined property: Index::$Index_Model` . But when I uncomment the `$this->load->model( 'Index_Model' );`, I get out of memory exceptions.

What's the right way to call `getIndexListing()` so I can populate my page? Did I misname my classes or files?

Comment: It might be that in your controller you've commented out your model loading line: $this->load->model('Index_Model'); so your Index controller, as the error says, does not have a property $Index_Model defined.

Comment: And you can remove the  if (! isset($this->Index_Model)) check.  Codeigniter will only load the model once.

Comment: And you might want to return something from your getIndexListing() function you're not returning any value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all you need to change controller name as index is the reserved name http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Then you will have to have two different names for controller class and model class they cant be same as you cant have 2 classes with same name in same namespace. So let say you controller is whatever then it is good practice to have model class like whatever_model

Comment: Also models arent necessarily tied to controllers... the model should be named after the business object or db table it represents like.. in this case something like `Forum_Model`

Comment: I changed my model to be called `Index_Model`, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: You need to change controller name it can't be Index it is reserved name http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: This was exactly the primary problem, secondarily accompanied by the class/file naming conventions of PHP.